# Consuming Paginated API in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I'm just getting started with React. As a simple exercise, I wanted to create some components for viewing data retrieved from the [JsonMonk API](https://jsonmonk.com/). The API contains 83 user records and serves them in pages of 10.

I am trying to develop a component for viewing a list of users one page at a time which I called `UserList`. The code for it is below:

```js
class UserList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      pageNumber: 1,
      users: [],
    };

    this.onPageNext = this.onPageNext.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUsers(this.state.pageNumber)
      .then((users) => this.setState({users: users}));
  }

  async fetchUsers(pageNumber) {
    const response = await fetch(`https://jsonmonk.com/api/v1/users?page=${pageNumber}`);

    const jsonResponse = await response.json();

    return jsonResponse.data.records;
  }

  onPageNext() {
    // ...
  }

  render() {
    const postElements = this.state.users.map(
      (props) => <User key={props._id} {...props} />);

    return (
      <div>
        {postElements}
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.onPageNext}>Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem I am having pertains to the `onPageNext` method of my component. When the user clicks the "Next" button, I want to make a fetch for the next page of data and update the list.

My first attempt used an asynchronous arrow function passed to setState like so:

```js
  onPageNext() {
    this.setState(async (state, props) => {
      const nextPageNumber = state.pageNumber + 1;

      const users = await this.fetchUsers(nextPageNumber);

      return {pageNumber: nextPageNumber, users: users}
    })
  }
```

However, it does not seem React supports this behavior because the state is never updated.

Next, I tried to use promise `.then` syntax like so:

```js
  onPageNext() {
    const nextPageNumber = this.state.pageNumber + 1;

    this.fetchUsers(nextPageNumber)
      .then((users) => this.setState({pageNumber: nextPageNumber, users: users}));
  }
```

This works but the problem here is that I am accessing the class's state directly and not through `setState`'s argument so I may receive an incorrect value. Say the user clicks the "Next" button three times quickly, they may not advance three pages.

I have essentially run into a chicken-or-the-egg type problem. I need to pass a callback to `setState` but I need to know the next page ID to fetch the data which requires calling `setState`. After studying the docs, I feel like the solution is moving the fetch logic out of the `UsersList` component, but I'm not entirely sure how to attack it.

As always, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `onPageNext` as below:

```
onPageNext() {
        this.setState( prevState => {
            return {pageNumber: prevState.pageNumber + 1}
        }, () =>{
            this.fetchUsers(this.state.pageNumber).then(users => this.setState({users: users}) )
        });
    }
```

Here is the Complete Code:

```
import React from "react";

export default class UserList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            pageNumber: 1,
            users: [],
        };

        this.onPageNext = this.onPageNext.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchUsers(this.state.pageNumber)
            .then((users) => {
                    console.log(users, 'users');
                    this.setState({users: users})
                }
            );
    }

    async fetchUsers(pageNumber) {
        const response = await fetch(`https://jsonmonk.com/api/v1/users?page=${pageNumber}`);

        const jsonResponse = await response.json();

        return jsonResponse.data.records;
    }

    onPageNext() {
        this.setState( prevState => {
            return {pageNumber: prevState.pageNumber + 1}
        }, () =>{
            this.fetchUsers(this.state.pageNumber).then(users => this.setState({users: users}) )
        });
    }

    render() {
        const postElements = this.state.users.map(
            (user) => <User key={user._id} {...user} />);

        return (
            <div>
                {postElements}
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.onPageNext}>Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function User(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{padding: 5}}>Name: {props.first_name} {props.last_name}</div>
            <div style={{padding: 5}}>Email: {props.email}</div>
            <div style={{padding: 5}}>Phone: {props.mobile_no}</div>
            <hr/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**[Here is the Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/user-list-with-paging-vz9g7)**